# mongodb not working after install

Tags: linux, mongodb

I followed these steps at http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04/ as I usually do, since everyone on ubuntu knows the mongo docs don't work. I'm actually on kubuntu 15

I try to install mongo but it was already there:

```
cchilders:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 288 not upgraded.
```

Even though it exists I have no access at all:

```
cchilders:~$ sudo service mongod start
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
cchilders:~$ sudo service mongodb start
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
cchilders:~$ sudo service mongo start
Failed to start mongo.service: Unit mongo.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
cchilders:~$ mongostat
2016-02-23T20:20:54.775-0600    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
cchilders:~$ mongostat
2016-02-23T20:21:15.047-0600    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
cchilders:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
connecting to: test
2016-02-23T20:21:17.015-0600 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-02-23T20:21:17.016-0600 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt faied
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
cchilders:~$ sudo service mongod restart
Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

How can I get mongo to run if it's already installed? Thank you

Comment: FYI: I install MongoDB on Ubuntu _regularly_, and despite the fact I don't like the OS, the MongoDB docs work fine – if followed closely.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Support for Ubuntu 15.04](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742)

> The MongoDB team says they won't support Ubuntu 15.04 and plan to support 16.04 instead.

You can switch back to Upstart by installing `upstart-sysv`:

`sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv`

Then reboot and MongoDB should be started.